# How to set up Atom.io as a WinSCP external editor

Tags: winscp, atom-editor

How do I set up Atom (from [atom.io](https://atom.io)) as a WinSCP editor?

(based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29102822/using-atom-io-with-winscp)

Answer (score 3):

To ensure you are using the up-to-date atom editor, select the `atom.cmd` file as the external editor (you will have to show all files in the picker). The full value will look something like this:

```
C:\Users\joe.user\AppData\Local\atom\bin\atom.cmd !.!
```

Comment: that works /somehow/, however, it eats up the cpu and takes ages (meaning seconds) to open that file. really not useful. is there other command?

Comment: In contrast to providing "update.exe" (the same way the Atom shortcut is set up) this works, but it does spawn a separate Atom editor for each file if multiple files are selected, although "External editor opens each file in separate window (process)" is not selected. [Integration with Text Editors](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_editor) does not list Atom yet. It also spawns two windows if Atom.exe is provided directly.

Answer (score 3):

As atom registers itself in the PATH, I often launch it via CMD prompt via :

```
atom
```

So I registered a new editor in WinSCP like this :

```
atom !.!
```

And it seems to work, with multiple tabs activated

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget that the last versions of atom are changed, so you need to specify that atom opens all files in the same window, to do this add :

```
atom --add !.!
```

For more information , check [this link](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/aw/document-launch-behaviors/docs/launch-behavior.md)